# How to use block as a variable name in Perl

Tags: perl, reference

Guys I'm new to Perl and I am now in reference chapter, and this topic confuses me. I understand the concept of reference since I know C programming too. In the book I am reading says:

**"Not only can you dereference a simple variable name, you can also dereference the contents of a BLOCK. Anywhere you'd put an alphanumeric identifier as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type."**

I need an example on this part- "anywhere you'd put an alphanumerc identifier as part of a variable.... you can replace the identifier with a block" - exactly how would that happen?

and this example too:

```
&{ $dispatch{$index} }(1, 2, 3);
```

Can somebody explain that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` contains the name of a hash key.  `%dispatch` is the hash with said key.  The value associated with that key is a subroutine reference, which `&{}` dereferences.  It's invoked with `1, 2, 3` as its arguments.

This is a fine enough example, although I would generally write:

```
$dispatch{$index}->(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I am internalizing your answer. Still i am confuse with the parenthesis part. can you elaborate the `(1,2,3)`. Am i right when i say it's accessing the subroutine and passing the value (1,2,3) as parameters?

Comment: @BelmarkCaday, by "parenthesis part" you probably mean [the Arrow Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator).  Which link mostly directs you to perldoc perlreftut and perldoc perlref, which is what I'd recommend if you weren't already reading the latter.  The short explanation is "uh, it's equivalent to your example code."

Comment: shouldn't it be like this: `$dispatch{$index}(1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: Hey man, is the (1,2,3) the keys in the hash in which the values are function names? Is that right?

Comment: @BelmarkCaday, why would that be right?  What don't you understand about "`$index` contains the name of a hash key"?  Doesn't that suggest that `$index`, rather than anything else, is the key?  Doesn't "invoked with `1, 2, 3` as its arguments." suggest that those are arguments rather than keys? You said that you know C; what does does `blah(1, 2, 3);` look like to you as C?

Comment: ok no need to enrage. I'm just clarifying since i get different answers from different people (not just here in stackoverflow) Thanks a lot man, i understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

The quoted paragraph is saying that you're not limited to doing

```
my $handler = $displatch{$type} or die;  # Arbitrary code
my $ref = $handler->();                  # Arbitrary code
my @a = @$ref;
```

You can also do

```
my @a = @{ my $handler = $displatch{$type} or die; $handler->() };
```

Same goes for other dereferences.

```
$BLOCK
$BLOCK[ ... ]
$BLOCK{ ... }
@BLOCK
@BLOCK[ ... ]
@BLOCK{ ... }
%BLOCK
&BLOCK
&BLOCK( ... )
*BLOCK
```

Comment: sir @ikegami can you explain this part `@{ my $ref = f(); $ref = g() if !$ref; $ref }` and is it necessary to put the word "BLOCK" ?

Comment: It executes the code in the block, then dereferences the reference it returns. // No, you put an actual block, as in the example I showed.

Comment: You are assuming the `f()` or `g()` returns a list? the @{} dereferences this assumption, and stored in @a? Am i right?

Comment: No, a reference to an array. You can't get a reference to a list. I changed the example to make it clearer. It's not important what the code is. What's relevant is that it can be put where in curlies where `$ref` is expected.

Comment: so @a holds an address not the real data?

Comment: No, `$ref` holds an address (a reference). The elements of the array referenced by `$ref` are assigned to `@a`. None of this is related to the question you asked. You should understand `@$ref` before you try to understand a paragraph that says it can also be written as `@{ $ref }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub sample_function1 {
   ...
}
sub sample_function2 {
   ...
}

%dispatch = ( 'f1' => \&sample_function1,
              'f2' => \&sample_function2 );

$index = <STDIN>;
chomp $index;
&{ $dispatch{$index} }(1, 2, 3);
```

If the user enters `f1` this will call `sample_function1(1, 2, 3)`, if he enters `f2` it will call `sample_function2(1, 2, 3)`.

What the documentation is explaining is that you since you can write `sample_function1(1, 2, 3)`, you can replace the function name with a block containing code that returns a function reference.

Comment: and pass the (1,2,3) as parameters? is that right? why are you all forgetting the `(1,2,3)` part? :)

Comment: Ok i get it now. But the answer of that other guy confuses me more. His example is `$dispatch{$index}->(1, 2, 3)`. Where did that arrow come from? I know it's another way of dereferencing, but why is it used in a function call? Shouldnt it be like this: `$dispatch{$index}(1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: You need to use `->` to dereference a reference; after the arrow you put whatever would be used with an ordinary variable of the referenced type: parentheses for functions, curlies for hashes, brackets for arrays. But the alternative is to wrap it in a block as in the question.

Comment: `(1,2,3)` the keys in the hash in which their corresponding values are function names? Is that right?

Comment: `(1, 2, 3)` are the arguments to the function that you're calling. The keys are `f1`, `f2`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). You may have even used that before. It's one of the first Perl modules that many Perl programmers ever use.

The `find` command takes two arguments:

- The second (we'll start with the simple one) is a list of directories I want to search.
- The first argument is a bit trickier -- it's an actual subroutine my `find` command will use. The `find` command uses that subroutine to determine if a particular element in my directory tree matches the criteria I'm looking for. What `find` does is go through each and every element of my directory tree and passes that element to my subroutine. It's up to my subroutine to check the element to see if it passes muster.

Let's say I want to find all ***files*** in my directory that  have the suffix of `.txt`. In Unix, I could do this:

```
$ find $directory -type f -name "*.txt"
```

In Perl, I create a subroutine called `wanted`. The `find` command will pass to my `wanted` subroutine an element in my directory via the `$_` Perl variable. I can then test that element to see if it's a file that has a `.txt` suffix:

```
sub wanted {
    return unless -f;             #Return unless $_ is a file
    return unless /\.txt$/;       #Return unless that file has a `.txt` suffix
    print "$Find::File::name\n";  #It's a file that ends with .txt. Print it.
}
```

Now, all I have to do is get my `wanted` subroutine as the first parameter of my `find` command:

```
find ( \&wanted, $directory );
```

That's all there is to it. A real life example that you will (if you haven't already) run into really soon. In C programming parlance, the `wanted` subroutine would be called a [Callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) routine.